# Get RGB channels from a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have list of RGB images I would like to take each channel from a image in the list and reshape it.
However, I am having an issue extracting the channels from the list of arrays.

Please refer the below code;

`difference[0].shape`

Output;

`(1280,720,3)`

To get the first channel *width* and *height* in the first image in the list I tried;

`difference[0][0].shape`

But I get the answer; `(720,3)` which is the *width* and the number of channels. What I want is to get  is `(1280,720)` as the output.

Would anyone be able to help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `difference[0]` is a numpy array of shape `(1280,720,3)`, you can use `difference[0][:,:,0]` to access all the data for the first dimension.

`difference[0][:,:,0].shape` will give you `(1280, 720)`.

`difference[0][:,:,0].shape` will give you the red data.

`difference[0][:,:,1].shape` will give you the green data.

`difference[0][:,:,2].shape` will give you the blue data.